# Python logging with Loguru - passing correlation id to child thread

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, python-logging, loguru

I would like to log correlation id in every log messages via Loguru.  I tried to use `logger.contextualize(correlation_id=id)`.  It works in the parent thread but not the child thread.  How do I get the correlation id to be logged in the child thread as well?

```
logger.remove(0)
logger.add(sys.stderr, format="{time:MMMM D, YYYY HH:mm:ss} | {level} | {message} | {extra}")

class Client:
  def get_data(self):
    logger.info("get_data")

class ProcessThread(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, client):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.client = client
    
  def run(self):    
    logger.info("inside child thread")
    self.client.get_data()


def test(id):
  with logger.contextualize(correlation_id=id):
    process_thread = ProcessThread(Client())
    logger.info("inside parent thread")
    process_thread.start()

test('101')
```

Current output is

```
January 17, 2023 21:14:08 | INFO | inside parent thread | {'correlation_id': '101'}

January 17, 2023 21:14:08 | INFO | inside child thread | {}

January 17, 2023 21:14:08 | INFO | get_data | {}
```

But I want it to be

```
January 17, 2023 21:14:08 | INFO | inside parent thread | {'correlation_id': '101'}

January 17, 2023 21:14:08 | INFO | inside child thread | {'correlation_id': '101'}

January 17, 2023 21:14:08 | INFO | get_data | {'correlation_id': '101'}
```

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing the contextual information inside get_data() and run().

Just do `with logger.contextualize(correlation_id=id):` for both of them and it should work.

[logger.contextualize loses the context when you go out of `with`](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/logger.html#loguru._logger.Logger.contextualize)